# PDFTron: convert to jpeg with better quality

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, jpeg

I'm trying to convert a PDF page to JPEG with PDF Tron:

```
Obj encoder_param = (new ObjSet()).CreateDict();
encoder_param.PutNumber("Quality", 100);
draw.Export(doc.GetPage(i), tmpSketchFileName, "JPEG", encoder_param);
```

But the quality of the sketch is poor! Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I've tried PNG and TIFF formats, but it still leaves much to be desired.

Comment: Quality? As in resolution, or in correct colors?

Comment: This question would be much improved with the addition of suitably sized screenshots (input and output) so we can see what you mean.

Comment: I suspect you need to set the DPI to render at.

Comment: The text is blurred as on a scanned page of a book. Please, could you provide some code how to set DPI?

Comment: Not sure if this helps but you may try to use online api http://www.convertapi.com/api/pdf-image-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Ben commented, does increasing the DPI improve the output?

e.g `draw.SetDPI(300);`